# What is wrong with my Google kickstart round C Python code?

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop

### Can you solve this problem in Python3 and see what is wrong with my code?

Problem: 
Avery has an array of N positive integers. The i-th integer of the array is Ai.

A contiguous subarray is an m-countdown if it is of length m and contains the integers m, m-1, m-2, ..., 2, 1 in that order. For example, [3, 2, 1] is a 3-countdown.

Can you help Avery count the number of K-countdowns in her array?

Input: 
The first line of the input gives the number of test cases, T. T test cases follow. Each test case begins with a line containing the integers N and K. The second line contains N integers. The i-th integer is Ai.

Output: 
For each test case, output one line containing Case #x: y, where x is the test case number (starting from 1) and y is the number of K-countdowns in her array.

Limits 
Time limit: 20 seconds per test set. 
Memory limit: 1GB. 
1 ≤ T ≤ 100. 
2 ≤ K ≤ N. 
1 ≤ Ai ≤ 2 × 105, for all i.

Test set 1: 
2 ≤ N ≤ 1000.

Test set 2: 
2 ≤ N ≤ 2 × 105 for at most 10 test cases. 
For the remaining cases, 2 ≤ N ≤ 1000.

Sample:

```
Input

3
12 3
1 2 3 7 9 3 2 1 8 3 2 1
4 2
101 100 99 98
9 6
100 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 100

Output

Case #1: 2
Case #2: 0
Case #3: 1
```

In sample case #1, there are two 3-countdowns as highlighted below.
1 2 3 7 9 **3 2 1** 8 3 2 1
1 2 3 7 9 3 2 1 8 **3 2 1**

In sample case #2, there are no 2-countdowns.

In sample case #3, there is one 6-countdown as highlighted below.
100 7 **6 5 4 3 2 1** 100

This is my code

```
t = int(input())
# list 'numbers' store the number of countdowns in each testcase
numbers = []
for i in range(t):
    n, k = map(int, input().split()) 
    li = list(map(int, input().split()))
    # count the number of elements in countdown
    c1 = 1  
    # count the numbers of countdowns that match K
    c2 = 0
    for i in range(n-1):
        if li[i]-li[i+1] == 1:
            c1 += 1
        else:
            if c1 == k:
                c2 += 1
            c1 = 1
        print(c1, c2)
    numbers.append(c2)
for x in range(t):
    print('Case #{}: {}'.format(x, numbers[x]))
```

Comment: You'd need to check if c1 == k at the end of the loop too, to catch a 3-2-1 that ends at the end of the array.

Comment: And you should count any countdown that ends in a 1 if it is length >= k to cover the third case.